# Missing files in Windows 2008+VHD+SSD

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssd, vhd

I have running Windows 2008 Server machine on my SSD disc from VHD file. Today while I was working with Windows the 30% of files disappeared. There are only folders left and no files. I can't find some of files in User folder and Program Files but not all. I can't start any program but Windows working fine. Maybe someone know what is going on?

Comment: Have you made any changes to the machine because it sounds like something has become corrupt.  You might have to restore from a backup that you do have....right?

Comment: @Shads0 I just working with Visual Studio 2010 and suddenly the running programs have started faulting. I have checked HDD(c:\) and the free space increased by about 30% in my eyes. Never saw anything before. I can't start any program or find my personal files but strange thing is that Windows itself running fine.

Comment: @Tomas You do have a backup for the machine, right? (Hint hint)

Comment: Yes, I have VHD file backup, but I would like to find out what is just happened with my OS.

Answer (score 0):

You might suffer from a filesystem corruption. Run `chkdsk /F <your drive>` to check for possible errors. You might have to restart your system if `<your drive>` is the system drive.

Comment: Done that and got no errors.

Comment: The next shot would be a malware infection. Try scanning with an AV of your choice.